# Self promotion in tags

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I came across a tag edit in my review queue, wherein the author had edited the tag wiki to insert another tutorial relating to the tag into it's wiki. I followed the link and went to the site to discover that the blog was by the author themself.

I rejected the edit with the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

which was the closest to what I felt should be the reason. But I don't think this applies correctly either. Isn't there a "Self Promotion" type reason for closing tag-edits too?

Comment: Just pick 'does harm' and explain that self-promotion is harmful (spamming).

Comment: I don't see much wrong with [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6673113). How is it "harmful"?

Comment: ... and just on a sidenote, **WOW!** the question has so much discussion going on here on Meta, and I'm not even notified once by the counter at the top!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : It's not harmful in the sense that its benign. But adding a like to *your own* blog, and that too when it's 3 days old, and that too at the top of the stack of clearly more useful links, doesn't do anyone much good.

Comment: @Kumar: The counter tells you about rep, not activity. And, since you cannot accrue rep from meta... Consider [voting for this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648/155739)!

Comment: No, I don't thing I'd require rep for this... Btw, the counter **does** tell me about mentions, like you did to me, and I've done right now to you @LightnessRacesinOrbit. So, why not notify about items on my own questions!?!?

Comment: @KumarHarsh: Oh, right, I see what you mean. Well then I don't know

Answer (score -13):

> Ah it was my edit.. good work @kumar **IF** it was harmful..
>
> **Edit:** First I am not against my edit being rejected. But it **wasnt a spam or it didnt harm anything**  edits like these should be rejected for some other reason

As it is my blog.. I find it very useful for newbies.. maybe **I am wrong!**

And as (According to me) it is helpful I just added url of my blog(which i recently started writing) hoping it might help newbies ff someone comes across it. If this  was really a harmful Then Its all-right I haven't even linked it in this answer.

So far I know, **spamming is when user links something which is not useful and related** , I dont understand what spamming means related to this post.

I hope I get an answer on this if it is a right thing or not? (posting as an answer becoz *cant resist it*)

> **Edit:** Ok from comments below, i understand i shouldnt have done that.
>   Or atleast i should have asked on meta before adding a link to a self
>   blog. Thanx freinds.

Comment: Most people view posting links to your own stuff as self-promotion - who knows if what you post is even correct? It's up to the community at large to decide if your stuff is factual and useful - not you.

Comment: You have, what, 2 posts on your blog? That just reeks of spamming. Sorry. Get more *quality* content on there, for starters.

Comment: Ok.. I was just saying it wasnt a spam at all. thats it. and also one of the comments above frommartijn says `does harm` I dont agree.. probably my edit should be rejected but not as does harm or spamming.. It should have been rejected for some other reason

Comment: Posting your own website is self-promoting and is therefore spam, especially with only 2 posts on your own blog. The best way to report spam is by choosing the `does harm` flag, which does not mean your website is harmful in anyway, but spam in general is.

Comment: Posting your own website is not self promoting if the content is relevent to the topic.. And spamming is something which is posted irrelevant..  My edit does nothing of these..

Comment: If someone who is already regarded as an expert on the subject does it, it would probably slide by. Someone who has 2 posts on his blog is obviously just trying to game whatever little SEO juice they can.

Comment: Oh.. SEO juice is done when there is some profit.. I dont have any ads on my blog.. Did you see

Comment: Posting a link to your blog in an answer or comment is one thing, as the community can up/down-vote and provide feedback on how useful it is. Adding it to a semi-permanent tag wiki is far more questionable.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh This is irrelevant! Spam is unwanted content, whether or not the content is relevant. It doesn't matter if you had ads on your blog or not, there is potential for you to change that content without notice - ads, adult content, etc (not saying that's what you were going to do, just that it's possible) - and when put in a tag wiki it is very suspicious.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh : I do see your point, and I was myself not very sure that the category I chose what correct, but I'd clicked on the choice, and wasn't able to review that choice. But, *and this is just my viewpoint*, I had a look at your blog. OK, It's on Nodejs, but it's just one post, and that too the most basic `how to create an express app`. There are already countless ones like those. You'd have to write a **lot** more to be considered useful for addition to the wiki.

Comment: understood @KumarHarsh.. Thanx you raised this on meta.. helped me to understand this shouldnt be done :)